# @PostConstruct on parametrised bean

Tags: java, spring, java-11, lombok

I have parametrised interface and parametrised class that implements this interface. Than I inject this class into 3 services and set typeParameterClass in @PostConstruct method. 2 classes return correct typeParameterClass, but other one returns typeParameterClass from another service and not the one that was setted in this class in @PostConstruct.

Like

```
ClassOneServiceImpl.getParameter() = ClassOne.class;
ClassTwoServiceImpl.getParameter() = ClassTwo.class;
ClassThreeServiceImpl.getParameter() = ClassOne.class;
```

I've added logging to initialisation, however I see that setted TypeParameterClass in setTypeParameterClass(Class clazz) is correct.

In local environment on jdk-17 Temurin the program is working fine.

Any suggestions why @PostCOnstruct not working as expected? Or may be the problem can occur in other places?

```
public interface PostgresDAO<T> {
    void setTypeParameterClass(Class<T> clazz);
    Entity findEntityById(Long id);
}


@Repository
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
public class PostgresDAOImpl<T> implements PostgresDAO<T> {

    private Class<T> typeParameterClass

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;

    @Override
    public void setTypeParameterClass(Class<T> clazz) {
        this.typeParameterClass = clazz;
    }

    **** some code with EntityManager
    
}
```

And I have 3 services that are using PostgresDAOImpl with different parameter.

```
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class ClassOneServiceImpl implements ClassOneService {

    private final PostgresDAO<ParameterOne> dao;

    @PostConstruct
    public void enrichDao() {
        dao.setTypeParameterClass(ParameterOne.class);
    }

    public Class getParameter() {
        return dao.getTypeParameterClass();
    }

    ***** some code

}


@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class ClassTwoServiceImpl implements ClassTwoService {

    private final PostgresDAO<ParameterTwo> dao;

    @PostConstruct
    public void enrichDao() {
        dao.setTypeParameterClass(ParameterTwo.class);
    }

    public Class getParameter() {
        return dao.getTypeParameterClass();
    }

    ***** some code

}


@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class ClassThreeServiceImpl implements ClassThreeService {

    private final PostgresDAO<ParameterThree> dao;

    @PostConstruct
    public void enrichDao() {
        dao.setTypeParameterClass(ParameterThree.class);
    }

    public Class getParameter() {
        return dao.getTypeParameterClass();
    }

    ***** some other code

}
```

javax.annotation dependency added

```
        <!--need for postconstruct annotation in java 11 https://www.baeldung.com/spring-postconstruct-predestroy-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.annotation</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.annotation-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.2</version>
        </dependency>
```

Setup

- lombok 1.18.22
- spring-boot 2.7.0

openjdk version "11.0.4" 2019-07-16 LTS

OpenJDK Runtime Environment 18.9 (build 11.0.4+11-LTS)

OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 18.9 (build 11.0.4+11-LTS, mixed mode, sharing)

Answer code:

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
public class PostgresDAOConfig {
    @Bean
    public PostgresDAO<ParameterOne> deceptionDAO() {
        PostgresDAOImpl<ParameterOne> result = new PostgresDAOImpl<>();
        result.setParameterClass(ParameterOne.class);
        return result;
    }
    @Bean
    public PostgresDAO<ParameterTwo> deceptionDAO() {
        PostgresDAOImpl<ParameterTwo> result = new PostgresDAOImpl<>();
        result.setParameterClass(ParameterTwo.class);
        return result;
    }
    @Bean
    public PostgresDAO<ParameterThree> deceptionDAO() {
        PostgresDAOImpl<ParameterThree> result = new PostgresDAOImpl<>();
        result.setParameterClass(ParameterThree.class);
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: Does `ParameterThree` extend `ParameterOne`?

Comment: No, they are independant classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am surprised it works locally because it should not. By default Spring beans are singletons and with your code example you inject the same bean in all `ClassOne`, `ClassTwo` and `ClassThree` services. In the `PostConstruct` method you just override the parameter class.

To address this, you create three `PostgresDAOImpl` repositories in a `@Configuration` annotated class and inject each one in the relevant service. If you go like this most likely you don't even need the `PostConstruct` method at all.